# GNS3 Dynamips error

Tags: iso-image, emulator

When I'm trying to start `dynamips.exe` I'm getting the following error:

```
dynamips.exe 

The procedure entry point PacketGetReadEvent could not 
be located in the dynamic link library packet.dll
```

I have `packet.dll` installed at my x32 and x64 system folders.

Comment: Do you have the correct version of `packet.dll` which goes with `dynamips.exe` ? It sounds like you have the wrong version, or a different library entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Darth, Can you be more specific, As Where can i get the correct version or i do i know what is the correct version?...

Comment: I don't know, it was more of a question along the lines of did you run the installer, and it gave you that when you tried to open it, or did you have to go find `packet.dll` on the internet, and you manually downloaded and copied it into the folder? `dynamips.exe` is looking for a particular function in `packet.dll`, but it can't find it, which usually means that you don't have the right `packet.dll`.